How to programmatically add a small database to a Windows Forms project?
I recently finished my first little windows form app, but I used Access to make a database to populate the dropdowns, and it seems to want the user to have a silly database driver. I decided given how small the database is it would be better to just write it all out.
Basically I need to make 3 tables with 5-6 items each, with a display value and a secondary value, and use them to populate my dropdowns.
What's the best practice for something like this? make a class with two values, and put them in an ArrayList? populate it one item at a time and assign the secondary value later? or is there a smoother way that's more built into C#? I made the app for my portfolio so I want to make sure its done "right".
Clarification: The data are read-only. The user will not be able to edit these values.

You also may want to use Dapper which automatically populates the class objects and lists described by Ali. Instead of Access, you could use SQLite as a database. This has the advantage that you don't need to install any database server or application, since the whole code required is integrated in your application. (However, it simplifies the development if you install the SQLiteStudio.)

Do you want the database to be read-only, or the user should be able to make changes to the data?

Oliver thank you! Thats an excellent suggestion!

Theodor, the user will not be able to edit these values.

"it seems to want the user to have a silly database driver". There's nothing silly about it. Every database needs a database engine. If you use an ACCDB file then you will need the ACE provider, which means that the user will either need Microsoft Office installed or the standalone ACE provider. If you use an MDB file then you can use the Jet provider, which is basically part of Windows, so there's nothing extra needed. While there are generally better options than Access, including the suggested SQLite, you can still use Access and not require anything extra.

3 tables with 5-6 items each - You don't need a database at all. Just (de)serialize the data to/from a file.

Why do you need a database? If you've used a database, hopefully you learned about database normalization. For such a small amount of data, you may consider a text file, XML, or JSON.

Using the database was a choice that was about demonstrating proficiency in integrating a database and less about efficency. This is my first entry in my portfolio so I just wanted to flex "i can do database stuff" but clearly Access was not the way to go for the actual end users.

And yes, J, my main takeaway is "while access worked for my homework, I dont think i'll be using it on any future passion projects"

Putting data into a database, doesn't prove that you can do database stuff, particularly if you didn't normalize it.

The following uses Dapper which is added to your project as a NuGet package. Getting started page.
To interact with a table in a database create a class where the properties represent a column in the table. In the class Category ToString is overridden so that when presented in a ComboBox the overridden value, name of the category is shown.
Microsoft Access is fine to get your feet wet but better off using SQLite which is installed as an NuGet package here.

/*
 * For the dropdown, set DropDownStyle to DropDownList
 */
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingList<Category> _bindingCategories;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += Form1_Shown;
    }

    private async void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataOperations dataOperations = new();
        
        _bindingCategories = new BindingList<Category>(
            await dataOperations.GetCategories());

        CategoriesComboBox.DataSource = _bindingCategories;
    }

    private void GetCategoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Category category = _bindingCategories[CategoriesComboBox.SelectedIndex];
        MessageBox.Show($"{category.Identifier} {category.CategoryName}");
    }
}

// place in its own file
public class Category
{
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => CategoryName;
}
// place in its own file
public class DataOperations
{
    private IDbConnection _cn = new OleDbConnection("Your connection string");
    public async Task<List<Category>> GetCategories()
        => (await _cn.QueryAsync<Category>(
            "SELECT Identifier, CategoryName FROM Categories")).AsList();
}

Screenshot

